# Reading XML with a colon (:)

Tags: c#, xml-namespaces, xmldocument, selectsinglenode

I'm trying to get the views of a video from the following XML document (https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=example), I'm able to get the link and the autor because there is no colon in the tag.

I'm trying to get yt:statistics but I've no idea how.

```
    result = e.Result.Replace("xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' ", String.Empty);

    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(result);

    XmlNodeList videos = doc.GetElementsByTagName("entry");

    foreach (XmlNode video in videos)
    {
        XmlNode insideauthor = video.SelectSingleNode("author");

        string videoId = video.SelectSingleNode("id").InnerText.Replace("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/", String.Empty);
        string author = insideauthor.SelectSingleNode("name").InnerText;

        // Trying to get the views of a video of the search results
        MessageBox.Show(video.SelectSingleNode("yt:statistics").Attributes["viewCount"].InnerText);
    }
```

Comment: You should learn to work with namespaces properly rather than using hacky string replacements to avoid them. If the operators of this feed decided to start using namespace prefixes on their `entry` elements, your application would break for no good reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
XmlNodeList videos = doc.GetElementsByTagName("entry");

foreach (XmlNode video in videos)
{
    string videoId = video["id"].InnerText.Replace("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/", String.Empty);
    string author = video["author"]["name"].InnerText;
    string views = video["yt:statistics"].Attributes["viewCount"].Value;

    Console.WriteLine(videoId);
    Console.WriteLine(author);
    Console.WriteLine(views);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know it was that easy!

Comment: Still works today - much better than mucking about with multiple namespaces, HOWEVER, SelectSingleNode has an overload for namespace manager. (probably best to go that route, ultimately, but coolmine's answer will work)